# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to put a JSON response from a web service into an object that I can pass to my view and display the results of. I seem to be having some issues deserializing the JSON. Here is the error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Project.Models.Order' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

My controller code is as follows.

```
string url = @"URL of webservice here";

var returnValue = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(returnValue);

return View(obj);
```

Here is my view.

```
@model Project.Models.Order

@foreach (var order in Model.sWorkOrderNumber)
{
    @Model.sWorkOrderNumber
}
```

Here is the JSON that is getting returned.

```
[{"ShipmentTrackingNUmbers":[{"sTrackingNumber":"Redacted"}],"dtDateShipped":"5/12/2017 12:00:00 AM","dSPRatedWeight":"41.0000","nMBTotalBoxes":"1","sShipToAddressLine2":"Redacted","sShipToCountry":"U.S.A.","sShipToZip":"Redacted","sShipToState":"Redacted","sShipToCity":"Redacted","sShipToAddressLine1":"Redacted","sShipToName":"Redacted","sServiceLevel":"GND","sInvoiceNumber":"","dtInvoiceDate":"","mInvoiceAmount":"","dtDateReceived":"5/8/2017 3:16:25 PM","sStudioCategory2":"","sStudioCategory1":"","sOrderSource":"Redacted","sCustomerComments":"Redacted","sCustomerOrderName":"Redacted","sWorkOrderNumber":"Redacted","sCustomerNumber":"Redacted"},{"ShipmentTrackingNUmbers":[{"sTrackingNumber":"Redacted"}],"dtDateShipped":"5/10/2016 12:00:00 AM","dSPRatedWeight":"3.0000","nMBTotalBoxes":"1","sShipToAddressLine2":"","sShipToCountry":"U.S.A.","sShipToZip":"Redacted","sShipToState":"Redacted","sShipToCity":"Redacted","sShipToAddressLine1":"Redacted","sShipToName":"Redacted","sServiceLevel":"GND","sInvoiceNumber":"","dtInvoiceDate":"","mInvoiceAmount":"","dtDateReceived":"5/2/2016 7:18:41 AM","sStudioCategory2":"","sStudioCategory1":"","sOrderSource":"Redacted","sCustomerComments":"Redacted","sCustomerOrderName":"Redacted","sWorkOrderNumber":"Redacted","sCustomerNumber":"Redacted"}]
```

Edit: Adding Order Model Code

```
namespace Project.Models
{
public class Order
{
    public string ShipmentTrackingNUmbers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string dtDateShipped
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string dSPRatedWeight
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string nMBTotalBoxes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToAddressLine2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToCountry
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ShipToZip
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToState
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToCity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToAddressLine1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sShipToName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sServiceLevel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sInvoiceNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string dtInvoiceDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string mInvoiceAmount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string dtDateReceived
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sStudioCategory2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sStudioCategory1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sOrderSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sCustomerComments
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sCustomerOrderName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sWorkOrderNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sCustomerNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
I have tried every which way to get this to format correctly and cannot get it to work. Any guidance would be amazing.

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: How does the ```Order``` object look like?

Comment: Please add the code for your model `Order`

Comment: I think you may need to use ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(returnValue)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model should look something like this. Note that `ShipmentTrackingNUmbers` is a `List`

```
class Shipment
{
    public List<ShipmentTrackingNUmbers> ShipmentTrackingNUmbers { get; set; }
    public string dtDateShipped { get; set; }
    public string dSPRatedWeight { get; set; }
    public string nMBTotalBoxes { get; set; }
    public string sShipToAddressLine2 { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentTrackingNUmbers
{
    public string sTrackingNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize the `returnValue` as a List of Shipments

```
List<Shipment> shipments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shipment>>(returnValue);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP's Model is incorrect and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct my Model was incorrect, the items can have multiple tracking numbers. Now I need to figure out how to modify the View to reflect these changes. Thanks again for the help!